# ASP Checkbox boolean value

Tags: asp.net, oracle, checkbox, boolean

My ASP detailsview and Gridview have a bunch of checkboxes bound to fields right now that are in an Oracle database. To my knowledge, Oracle doesn't actually have a Boolean value (Y/N instead).

Right now, I'm using the System.Data.OracleClient provider (I don't intend on changing this). However, if a box is checked, the "true" value is equal to 1 where as the database we have maintained requires true to equal -1.

Does anyone know of a way to change the value of "true" from 1 to -1 without using code behind?

Comment: If you don't want to use code-behind, the only other option I see is using triggers (assuming Oracle has something like a SQL trigger) to switch your 1 to -1.  But that could have some unforeseen consequences if you ever really DO want to put a 1 in there...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1413114.aspx/1) is what you're looking for?

Also these links helped me out:

1. [Evaluate SQL data type to checkbox  The Official Microsoft ASP_NET Forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1228883.aspx/1)
2. [DBNull' is a type and cannot be used as an expression  The Official Microsoft ASP_NET Forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1302238.aspx/1)